# Insert emoticon into the input field in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am using the `ngx-emoji-picker` in order to get emoticons available in message/input field... The plugin seems to work fine, but I'm not sure how should I handle the click event, so the selected emoticon gets appended next to the text that was inserted previously, for example "Hello John Doe + :emoticon:". The event.chat gets console-logged but I'm not sure how to combine it with a message...

```
            <input
                class="my-message"
                matInput
                placeholder="Type something..."
                name="text"
            />

            <span 
                class="material-icons emoticon" (click)="emoticonToggled = !emoticonToggled"
                [(emojiPickerIf)]="emoticonToggled"
                [emojiPickerDirection]="'bottom' || 'top' || 'left' || 'right'"
                (emojiPickerSelect)="handleEmoticonSelection($event)"
            >
                face
            </span>

            public emoticonToggled: boolean = false;

            handleEmoticonSelection(event) {
                console.log(event.char);
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, this is how it should be solved. The only thing is missing, an ngModel, which refers to the content of your input.

***.component.html**:

```html
...
            <input
                [(ngModel)]="inputText"
                class="my-message"
                matInput
                placeholder="Type something..."
                name="text"
            />
...
```

***.component.ts**:

```js
...
public inputText = '';

handleEmoticonSelection(event) {
 this.inputText += event.char;
}
```

Comment: I think `inputText` should be `this.inputText`.

Comment: Correct, I fixed it

Comment: Ahhh, thanks! So, the ngModel is like a reference to the input field? Thanks a ton

Comment: Exactly, I'm happy that I could help :)